# retrieving only required element from child objects Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am having a document as

```
{
owner:[
    {
        '_id':ObjectId(''),
        'userName':'sasasa',
        'name':"Sasa Sa"
    },
    ....
    ....
],
team:[
    {
        'name':'team 1',
        'member':[
            'sasasa',
            'aarwalka',
            'john'
        ]
    }
],
matches:[{
    'id':ObjectId(),
    'name':'cricket',
    'players':[
        {
            '_id':ObjectId(''),
            'userName':'sasasa',
            'name':"Sasa Sa"
        },
        .....
        .....
    ],
    'sponsors':[
        {
            '_id':ObjectId(''),
            'userName':'sasasa',
            'name':"Sasa Sa"    
        },
        .....
        .....
    ]
}]}
```

I need to make a query for all the usernames, that is, owner userName, team members, players & sponsors for a particular match(based on _id).

I have tried to achieve by *$project* & *$aggregation* , *$filter* But unable to arrange the user name for players and sponsors. Glad to have any suggestion to achieve this.

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly you want to do please?

Comment: Actually I want an array of the userNames associate with the match, something like
*[ sasasa, aarwalka, john,...]*

Answer (score 0):

Ok if i understood correctly based on a specific document `_id` you want the names of the people associated with the document.

All we have to do is group the names step by step

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    {
        $match: {
            // your initial match here
        }
    },
    // starting with getting owners.
    {
        $unwind: {
                path: "$owner",
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "all",
            owners: {$addToSet: "$owner.userName"},
            team: {$first: "$team"},
            matches: {$first: "$matches"},
        }
    },
    // just repeat same two steps for the others
    {
        $unwind: {
                path: "$team",
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
                path: "$team.member",
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
    },
    {
        $group: {
                _id: "all",
                owners: {$first: "$owners"},
                teams: {$addToSet: "$team.member"},
                matches: {$first: "$matches"},
            }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
                path: "$matches",
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
                path: "$matches.players",
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
    },
    {
        $group: {
                _id: "all",
                owners: {$first: "$owners"},
                teams: {$first: "$teams"},
                matches: {$addToSet: "$matches.players.userName"},
                sponsors: {$first: "$matches.sponsors"}
            }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$sponsors",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    },

    {
        $group: {
            _id: "all",
            owners: {$first: "$owners"},
            teams: {$first: "$teams"},
            matches: {$first: "$matches"},
            sponsors: {$addToSet: "$sponsors.userName"}
        }
    },
    // finally just concat all the arrays.
    {
        $project: {
            result: { $setUnion: [ "$owners", "$teams",  "$matches", "$sponsors"] }

        }
    }
])
```

- You can write this aggregation more 'elegantly' using [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) in a projection phase on each of the arrays at once however i felt for readability its better we take this step by step.